# How to create a simple edit button on crud?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, bootstrap-modal, crud

i'm trying to make a simple Crud for my homework . most of my code works properly for the most part, except the edit button. it only edits the first row. below, i provide my TS code along with my HTML. for the HTML i'm using Modal windows. so everytime i click on the edit buttons. a modal will appears

```js
function create() {
  let user: string = String($("#username").val());
  let data: JQuery = $("<tr id='crudData'><td>" + user + "</td><td><button class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#crudModal'>Bearbeiten</button></td></tr>");
  $("#crud").append(data);
}


function edit() {
  let user2: string = String($("#username2").val());
  let data2: JQuery = $("<tr id='crudData'><td>" + user2 + "</td><td><button class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#crudModal'>Bearbeiten</button></td></tr>");
  $("#crudData").replaceWith(data2);
}

$("#userbstg").on("click", create);
$("#saveEdit").on("click", edit);
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <h3 class="section-heading">Aufgabe - Usermanager</h3>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input id="username" class="form-control col-md-3" type="text">
        <button id="userbstg" class="btn btn-info">Add</button>
        <table id="crud" class="col-md-4 table">
          <tr>
            <th class="col-2" id="user">User</th>
            <th class="col-2" id="edit"></th>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="crudModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <label for="username2">Username:</label>
          <input id="username2" class="form-control col-md-12" type="text">
          <button type="button" id="saveEdit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you include the html?

Comment: @Ace just added my HTML

Comment: When you add a username row, you're adding an element with the id 'crudData' every time. Each row should have a unique id. Whenever you try to search for an element with that id, when your editing, it just find the first element with that id. Also, you have no way of telling the second input which row it's suppose to be editing.